# Send url patterns to C sockets retrieve it

Tags: c, sockets, server

I'm trying to build an application that can behave like a real server which can connect multiple clients and dispatch the path to respond to different urls.

Can we send a url like

```
127.0.0.1:32000/urlPath/OtherSubPath
```

to a server socket build using `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`? And get the url string at the server side? My server socket code looks like this.

```
sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

servaddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
servaddr.sin_port = htons(32000);
```

Below is a part of the code.

```
int sockfd, n;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
socklen_t len;
char mesg[1000];

servaddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // htonl(INADDR_ANY); //inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
servaddr.sin_port = htons(32000);


if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr)) == -1)
    error("Can't bind the port");


len = sizeof (cliaddr);

time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
//  printf("IP %s\n", servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
char* banner = "Hello UDP client! This is UDP server";


struct timeval stop, start;

pthread_t t0;
if (pthread_create(&t0, NULL, request_balancer, NULL) == -1) {
    printf("Error in pthread for request balance");
}

if (listen(sockfd, 10) == -1)
    error("Can't listen");

while (1) {
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    unsigned int address_size = sizeof (client_addr);

    int connect_d = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &address_size);

    if (connect_d == -1) {
        printf("Cannot open a socket");
        break;
    }
    web_req_count++;

    n = recvfrom(connect_d, mesg, 1000, 0, (struct
            sockaddr*) &cliaddr, &len);



    printf("Recieved: %d\n", web_req_count);
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {

        while (1) {
            banner = asctime(timeinfo);
            time(&rawtime);
            timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
            sleep(1);
            send(connect_d, banner, strlen(banner), 0);
            int line_cnt = 0;
            printf("Recieved \n");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If the code you show from the server is *all* the code you have, then no it won't be possible. Otherwise, it's possible to read just about anything from a *connected* socket.

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials on the subject. Accept the connection the spawn a thread/process to handle the request. It's good fun :)

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ would be a good starting point.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the tips. I did some diggings but I couldn't find that part. @Joachim I included some parts. Is it okey?

Comment: @Jasper looking that tutorial now :)

Comment: What is `len`? And this `unsigned int address_size` is definitly wrong. Depending on the platform `address_size` either has to be `socklen_t` (most UNIXes, but some still use(d) `size_t`) or `int` (Windows). **Check** the docs.

Comment: @alk I added the len it is socklen_t type. Sorry I'm new to C socket programming. I used Java but doing that in C is totally different. I will check for the docs. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Also (at least during development) compile with all warnings on (options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc) take the warnings serious and fix the code to have them go away (typcially **not** by wildly casting around). There are only few situations in C where casting is necessary (passing the 2nd argument to `accept()` is one of them).

Comment: @alk Thanks for that tip too. I used netbeans IDE as it was easy. I totally forgot warnings

Comment: When I was learning this, I found @Jasper's recommendation to be helpful for learning the basics, but IBM has a good (permissively licensed) example program that made everything clear at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/index.html